# jenkins pipeline: parameters in input message

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to know if is it possible to show, in a jenkins parmetrized build pipeline,  a parameter value inside a message of an input step.

```
ex:
input message: 'Input Data: \n\t ServerName: ${SERVERNAME_FQDN}\n\t 
Approve?', submitter: 'user1,user2'
```

thanks in advance,
Pietro

Comment: What happens when you add `echo SERVERNAME_FQDN`? I this variable really filled?

Comment: Before the input step there is an emailext step with the same variable and the value is correct.

Comment: Please create a minimal code example and post it completely here.

Comment: this is the emailext line before the input step, in the email sent by the plugin I see the value of the `${SERVERNAME_FQDN}` parameter
   
   
   `emailext( body: 'Installation Approval: \n Server: ${SERVERNAME_FQDN}\n\n link: ${PROJECT_URL} ')`

Comment: Ah.. Isn't that a special variable of the emailext plugin? Please try with `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double quoted GString to interpolate internal variables. For instance:

```
input message: "Input Data: \n\t ServerName: ${SERVERNAME_FQDN}\n\t Approve?", submitter: 'user1,user2'
```

should interpret variable `SERVERNAME_FQDN` and put its value in place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Szymon, but I already tried and the result is the same .

both in standard and bluocean interface.
Pietro